# Task relationship to Opportunity in sub query

Tags: apex, soql

I'm attempting to create a Batch class that will Stamp Opps with their Next Activity Date.

I haven't been able to figure out the **relationship between Opps and Tasks?** I’ve tried: Task_r, Tasks_r, Activities__r, Activity __r with no luck

Error: **Variable does not exist: Activities__r**

Thoughts?
Code:

```
public class BatchNextOpportunityActivity implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable{

//variable to hold any errors
private Set<String> apexErrors;

//List to hold Opportunities to be updated
List <Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List <Opportunity>();

//instantiate the class
public BatchNextOpportunityActivity(){
    
    Set<String> apexErrors = new Set<String>();
    this.apexErrors = apexErrors;

    List <Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List <Opportunity>();
    this.oppsToUpdate = oppsToUpdate;
}

public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Database.executeBatch( new BatchNextOpportunityActivity() );
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    
    String query =  'Select ID, Next_Activity__c,(ActivityDate FROM Activities__r  WHERE ActivityDate > Date,Today() ORDER BY ActivityDate desc) from Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate = LAST 120 DAYS';
    
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope){
    
    system.debug('scope.size = '+scope.size()); 
    
    for (Opportunity opp : scope){
        //If the ActivityDate of the 1st Task is greater than the Opps Next_Activity__c then let's update it with the Task's ActivityDate
        if (opp.Activities__r.size()>0 && opp.Activities__r[0].ActivityDate > opp.Next_Activity__c) {
            opp.Next_Activity__c = opp.Activities__r[0].ActivityDate;
            oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
        }
        
        //If there's no Tasks found and the Next_Activity__c field is populated lets clear it 
        Else if (opp.Next_Activity__c != null) {
            opp.Next_Activity__c = null;
            oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only add `__r` when it's a custom relationship.

Since the relationship between `Task` and `Opportunity` is a standard one, you don't add `__r`.

The child relationship name you're looking for here is `Tasks`, `Events`, or `ActivityHistories`

`SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Tasks) FROM Opportunity`

Comment: You forgot about OpenActivities. 

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the next open activity, your query should be:

```
SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1) FROM Opportunity
```

However, to avoid the "slow queue" for batch processing, the query should be performed in the execute method:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope){
    scope = [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :scope];
    // rest of logic here //
```

As a side note, don't use the String query method for getting the query locator, as it helps you avoid typos and accidentally renaming/deleting fields.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
```